# PostgreSQL Big Text Column Performance

Tags: postgresql, rails-postgresql

I am storing sent emails in a RDBMS including the to address, from address, and email body.

The body can really be any arbitrary amount of text, and I won't ever care to search on it.

Are there any performance issues I should worry about when having a potentially large column that isn't used too often in one of my most frequently accessed tables (Emails) ?

(This project is written in Rails)

Answer (score 14):

postgresql stores large objects in a secondary area. You can read about it here: [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/storage-toast.html).  The main concern will be keeping the large object out of the select list of queries that return many rows, so that you avoid visiting the secondary storage area.

If and when you do decide to add search functionality to the body text, you will need to use a full text strategy, which is well supported in Postgres, but is somewhat non intuitive.  The topic receives a [full chapter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-intro.html) of treatment in the manual.

Comment: That link doesn't mention it, but about full text search, you'll want to setup a GIN index on the text column. With that, full text search is insanely fast. I don't know why more people don't mention this PostgreSQL feature.

Answer (score 10):

No, you don't need to worry about that.

Technically there is no difference in storage between a e.g. `varchar(5)` and a `text` column.

Quote from the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

> there is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type

The three types mentioned there are `char`, `varchar` and `text`. Where `char` is the "blank-padded type".

Comment: That's not really true;  a `varchar(5)` is constrained to 9 bytes of storage, but a `text` (or plain `varchar`, without a size) can exceed the page size, which puts the actual data out of the page altogether.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: no, there is no difference in storage between those two. With the only exception that a varchar(5) will never be "toasted" as it does not exceed the threshold for compressing the value. 5 characters stored in a varchar(5) column are no different to 5 characters stored in a text column.